# NSDecimalNumber.adding from NSManagedObjects hitting unrecognized selector issue

Tags: swift, nsdecimalnumber

First, let me thank everyone in the SO community in advance for your help in getting me out of this jam.

My app hits a runtime error, and I've isolated the line causing the error.

When I attempt to add two NSDecimalNumber variables use the .adding method, I receive this "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber
>   decimalNumberByAdding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x608002c361a0'

I've created dummy NSDecimalNumber variables to try and debug this issue, and they seem to work fine when adding. However, when working with my NSManagedObject variables (`result` and `newTransaction`) which have NSDecimalNumber variables, I run into this error.

Below is the code that is causing these issues:

```
//Testing with dummy variables
let a1 = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 5.2)
let a2 = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 10.8)

print ("a1: \(a1), a2: \(a2)")         //a1: 5.2, a2: 10.8

let a3 = a1.adding(a2)

print ("a3: \(a3)")                    //a3: 16
//Great, everything above works fine.

//Now let's try using my NSManagedObjects, which were defined in another section
let a = result.netChange               //result.netChange is of class NSDecimalNumber
let b = newTransaction.amount          //newTransaction.amount is of class NSDecimalNumber

print ("a: \(a), b: \(b)")             //a: 444.12, b: 22.23

let c = a.adding(b)                    //<---This is where the app crashes

print ("c: \(c)")                      //Does not print, as the app has stopped
```

My question: Why are my dummy variables able to add with each other, while my NSManagedObject variables cannot?

Thanks again!

Comment: Did you define the property as "Decimal" in the Core Data model inspector? What does `print(type(of:result.netChange))` show?

Comment: @MartinR it shows "__NSCFNumber" for both 'result.netChange' and 'newTransaction.amount'

Comment: @MartinR I see where you were headed with this. I've updated the Core Data Model inspector - the variables are now of type Decimal (they were of type Double before). This has fixed the problem. Thanks for your help! How do I up vote your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A core data property of type "Double" is stored as `NSNumber` in the
managed object context. It is not sufficient to change the type in the
`NSManagedObject` subclass because the accessor methods are created
dynamically at runtime. Your code *compiles,* but crashes at runtime
because the variable is a `NSNumber` and not a `NSDecimalNumber`.

The solution is to set the type to "Decimal" in the Core Data model
inspector.